# Trying to make an initial commit

Tags: git, command-line

I'm trying to make my first commit on a new pre-existing project. My branch is up to date but when I try to make a commit I get this message:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   src/components/router/********
no changes added to commit
```

Note, I have not performed `git add`. Is that something you need to do?

Comment: Yes you need to do git add. But before everything else, please read a tutorial.

Comment: "Changes not staged for commit .. *no changes added* to commit".

Answer (score 1):

You must add the files to the index (`git add`) before committing them (`git commit`). As per the [`git commit` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

> Stores the current contents of the index in a new commit along with a log message from the user describing the changes.

The only exception would be to list the files in the `git commit` command directly with `-a` or `--interactive` or `--patch` option.

Comment: Nit: `git commit --allow-empty` (only for uh.. for 'never'? I've not found it useful.. maybe someone has)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example if you create a new file you have to add the files to git with git add. After that you can use git commit and git push.